# Can a queue worker signal failure to the parent?

Tags: python, multithreading

Imagine that I have a task queue with a consumer like this (this is almost identical to the sample code [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)):

```
def worker(tasks):
    while True:
        try:
            item = tasks.get_nowait()
        except:
            return
        execute(item)
        tasks.task_done()
```

and a producer like this:

```
def batch_execute(items, n_threads):
    tasks = Queue()
    for item in items:
        tasks.put(item)
    for n in range(n_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=tasks)
        t.start()
    tasks.join()
```

This works, except that execute(item) can throw exceptions. If that happens, the given thread will bail, the others keep running, and the tasks.join() will hang indefinitely. Both traits are undesirable. Is there a typical design people use to e.g. "forward" the exception from the child thread into the parent thread and unblock tasks.join()? Or do I have to manually implement all of that around python's Queue class?